# converting python code to javascript code

Tags: javascript

can somebody help for my code which is written in python, i want to write it in javascript but im in trouble, i dont know how.
python code

```
cities={}
for line in open("linnadkaugustega.txt", "r", encoding="UTF-8"):
    m=line.strip().split()
    abim=[word.split(":") for word in m[1:]]
    cities[m[0]]={}

    for couple in abim:
        cities[m[0]][couple[0]]=int(couple[1])

print(cities);
```

and i tried in javascript but that doesen't work

```
function tere(){
    console.log("Tere");
     $.get('read.txt', function(data) {
         cities={};
         var lines = (data.trim()).split();
         abim=[var word.split(":") for word in m[1:]]
         cities[m[0]]={};
         for var couple in abim
             cities[m[0]][couple[0]]=couple[1];
             console.log(cities);
    }, 'text');
}

tere();
```

can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax issues translating from python to js. Heres how arrays work...

if you have an array litteral in javascript

```
var cities = [];
```

Then we would add to the array by calling push

```
cities.push('Portland');
...
cities.push('New York');
```

we can then iterate over the array by calling forEach on the array object.

```
cities.forEach(function (city, index){
    //do work on each city
    console.log(city);
});
// Portland
// New York
```

Comment: can you help me to write my code correct ?

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- [`.split()` in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) does something different than [`split` in python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) when no separator is given. To split a line into words, you'll need to split on whitespaces explicitly
- you're missing the `for` loop over the lines of the file. Python uses the iterator syntax for reading from the file, in JavaScript an [ajax request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) loads the whole file and you'll need to split it in lines yourself.
- JavaScript does not have that `m[1:]` syntax, you'll need to use the [`.slice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead
- JavaScript does not have array/list comprehensions. You will need to use an explicit loop, or the [`map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) of arrays
- your loop syntax is too pythonic. In JavaScript, [`for` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) need parenthesis and an index variable.

So this should do (supposed you have the jQuery library loaded and it finds the file):

```
$.get('read.txt', function(data) {
    var cities = {};
    var lines = data.split("\n");
    for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
        var line = lines[i];
        var m = line.trim().split(/\s+/);
        var abim = m.slice(1).map(function(word) {
            return word.split(":");
        });
        var obj = cities[m[0]] = {};
        for (var j=0; j<abim.length; j++) {
            var couple = abim[j];
            obj[couple[0]] = couple[1];
        }
    }
    console.log(cities);
}, 'text');
```